# how can I catch all onsubmit event

Tags: jquery, onsubmit

I use this method to catch all form submit

```
$(function(){
   $("form").submit(function(){
       do somthing
   });
});
```

but,I can't catch this kind of submit

```
document.forms['form1'].submit();
```

why?

Comment: Because that is not a submit event, and doesn't even trigger a submit event, but submits the form. There are no other ways to submit the form, then calling it's submit method.

Comment: I look at this as a feature, it allows you to have a submit handler that prevents the submit event, then submits it after an asynchronous method such as a custom confirm dialog or some server-side validation without having to worry about going into an infinite loop or unbinding events.